# Generalist Badge - is this working

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I notice that not a single "Generalist" Badge has been awarded on this site. The way I understood may be incorrect. But I think quite a few would be eligible to get this badge.

Comment: The 40th tag just hit 200 questions, and 19 people were awarded the first of the generalist badges today.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [not documented in an easy-to-find way](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/), but a site must have at least 40 tags with 200+ questions in it before any Generalist badges are awarded. Since this site has only 27 tags with 200+ questions, the Generalist badge is not yet earnable.

Answer (score 3):

You may be right. I ran a badge progress report using [this script](http://data.stackexchange.com/money/query/76727/generalist-progression-updated) and it seems that I ought to have that badge, but don't.